# I can't get the previous posts link to show

Tags: php, wordpress

First of all, I've been all over Google, StackExchange and Codex but still can't solve my problem. It might be simple; am not sure. I have the following function that lists custom posts. The page has more than one query but only one (this one) make use of pagination. It's on the front page - which is set to static.

Here is the function:

```
function wight_listings()
{
    global $wp_query;
    global $page;

    $backup = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = NULL;
    $cur_page = $page; //get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

    $args = array(
            'post_type' => array('wight_listing'),
            'posts_per_page' => 7,
            'paged'=>$cur_page
        );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>
    <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        .
        .
        .
    <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div id="nav-posts" style="margin-top: .5em;">
            <div style="float:left;"><?php previous_posts_link('Previous Listings &laquo;'); ?></div>
            <div style="float:right;"><?php next_posts_link('&raquo; Next Listings'); ?></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
<?php  else: ?>
    <p>Oh no! There's nothing to show. :(</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
    $wp_query = NULL;
    $wp_query = $backup;
}
```

The 'Next listings' links shows up linking only to page 2 no matter what page am on and the 'Previous Listings' link never show up.

What am I doing wrong?

WP: 3.5.2

Comment: You are missing your opening and closing php tag or is it a copy/paste issue ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Where exactly? I cut the function short because it's quite long.

Comment: `<?php $wp_query = NULL; $wp_query = $backup;` is never closed in the code you supplied. But if you didn't supply the entire code it is possible that this is correct.

Comment: What happens if you properly clone the wp_query object, e.g. in your code replace `$backup = $wp_query` and `$wp_query = $backup` with `$backup = clone $wp_query` and `$wp_query = clone $backup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I looked into the /wp-includes/link-template.php and found the two functions responsible for my mysery. I copied them to my theme and modified a little and everything works fantastically.

```
function wight_get_previous_posts_page_link($cur_page)
{
    if ( $cur_page > 1 )
    {
        $nextpage = intval($cur_page) - 1;
        if ( $nextpage < 1 )
            $nextpage = 1;
        return '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($nextpage) . '">&laquo; Previous Listings</a>';
    }
}

function wight_get_next_posts_page_link($cur_page, $max_page)
{
    $paged = $cur_page;

    if ( !$paged )
        $paged = 1;
    $nextpage = intval($paged) + 1;

    if ( $max_page >= $nextpage )
        return '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($nextpage) . '">Next Listings &raquo;</a>';

}
```

Used those in place of previous_posts_link and next_posts_link.

```
<?php echo wight_get_previous_posts_page_link($cur_page); ?>
<?php echo wight_get_next_posts_page_link($cur_page, $query->max_num_pages); ?>
```

Comment: Well done for coming back and posting your answer and explanation.  Remember you should accept your own answer to show it's been solved - here's how to accept and answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Welcome to SO :)